# Typescript typing: Function with properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a Typescript decleration file for the Yargs js library.

How do I write the ambient type decleration for an external module with the dual behaviour ...

```
require('yargs').argv
```

and ...

```
require('yargs')([ '-x', '1', '-y', '2' ]).argv
```

Comment: Updated to clarify typescript context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare module "foo" {
    function M(argArray: any[]): typeof M;
    module M {
        export var argv;
    }

    export = M;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for answering. I don't think this makes M callable? Or does it? I need to do import argv = require("yargs"); argv(["-a","-b"]);

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I belive this is the solution. It satisfies the compiler. But the code completion in Webstorm 8 ... not so much :)

Comment: The code completion works as expected using a Eclipse Typescript plugin.

Comment: Webstorm code completion seems to have a lot of issues. Not sure what the deal with it is.

Comment: @user3572929 Please open a [bug report for WebStorm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) for this so that it can get fixed in the next release.

Comment: Added the bug report!

Answer (score 0):

This one was tricky.  It took some thinking.

```
declare module yargs {
    export interface Yargs {
        argv: string[];
        (input: string[]): Yargs;
        count(option: string): Yargs;
        alias(shrt: string, lng: string): Yargs;
    }
}

declare module "yargs" {
    var y: yargs.Yargs;
    export = y;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeffry! Yea I know ... this one was tricky :) This seems to pass the compiler. But the code completion in Webstorm 8 doesn't seem to cope as well as the compiler. When I do argv(["-a"]) ... the IDE can't  help me find the count, alias or the other members added to the interface yargs.Yargs.

Answer (score -1):

#### Simply export a function as the exported module.

For example:

```
// foo.js

function foo(args) {
  return {
    get: function() { return args; }
    size: args.length
  };
};

foo.bar = 'bar';

module.exports = foo;

// Example node usage.
require('./foo.js').bar // => 'bar'
f = require('./foo.js')([1,2,3]);
f.get(); // => [1,2,3]
f.size; // => 3
```

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I'm asking how to write a Typescript definition file, for a javascript library already doing something similar to your description.